# Applcation bar buttons with text in WP

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend, application-bar

I have application bar with some buttons and menu items when user clicks '...'. Anyway, I realized that meaning of some icons can be hard to understand at first sight.

Is it any way to display icons with text below them? Of course they are visible when user clicks '...' but also with menu items and I don't want it.

Anyone did that?

Comment: What's reasoning behind going against established UI behavior? What it's doing is what users would reasonably expect.

Comment: well, sometimes icons there may not have clear meaning for user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with a standard `ApplicationBar`. As I said the [default dehaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431813%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) is to hide the text.

Also WP7 user has a special user-expirience, so if he can't understand the meaning of your icon, he will press "..." to read the text.

But you can emulate an appbar in some scenarious:

```
<Border Background="{some gray color from phone resources}">
 <StackPannel Orientation="Horisontal">
  <Button Content={Binding TextB} Command="{Binging CommandA}" 
                          Style="{your appbar-like template}"/>
  <Button Content={Binding TextB}  Command="{Binging CommandB}" 
                          Style="{your appbar-like template}"/>
</StackPannel>
</Border>
```

Put it on the bottom of your page. But be ready to spend lot of time to emulate standard appbar behaviour. I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: I agree with you, but many times I get questions from non-wp persons about that and they were a bit suprised that '...' will show them more. For me it is also normal thing. Thanks for advices :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use shell:ApplicationBar and set Text property

```
<shell:ApplicationBar x:Name="dialogsPageAppbar">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton  IconUri="/images/Icons/appbar.add.rest.png" Text="create"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton  IconUri="/images/Icons/appbar.refresh.rest.png" Text="refresh"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton  IconUri="/images/Icons/appbar.feature.search.rest.png" Text="search"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="settings" />
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
```

Comment: This is normal way to make a button with text, but text appears when user clicks '...'. In default view you have just a metro icon without text. And I would like to see icon with text below as default view

Comment: If you don't need to loclize your app - draw an icon with text.

Comment: Anyway, a default behaviour is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431813(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: @AntonSizikov it won't fit inside, and even it will it most propably will be unreadable